# How to write a custom stop loss function in SIT R?

Tags: r

I am using Systematic Investor Toolbox (SIT) for backtesting my strategies in R. Currently I am using this function to use it as a [fixed stop loss](https://inovancetech.com/backtesttutorialr.html) in backtesting.

```
stop.loss <- function(weight, price, tstart, tend, pstop) {
index = tstart : tend
if(weight > 0)
price[ index ] < (1 - pstop) * price[ tstart ]
else
price[ index ] > (1 + pstop) * price[ tstart ]
}

#The stop loss function
Stoploss = .25/100
#Set our maximum loss at a .25% move in price against our trade

data$weight[] = NA
data$weight[] = custom.stop.fn(coredata(long.short.strategy), coredata(prices), stop.loss,pstop = Stoploss)
models$stoploss = bt.run.share(data, clean.signal=T, trade.summary = TRUE)
#Our long short model with a .25% stop loss
```

I want to create my own custom stop function in SIT but have no idea how and what parameters should be used in SIT for this purpose.

my custom stop loss idea is

```
1) Initially fixed stop loss should be 10% of entry price

2) when price move more than 20% of entry price a new fixed stop loss be made at 10% of new entry price
```

This is not a trailing stop loss because I dont want stop loss to trail the price but only move once.

Answer (score 2):

Have you already looked at this example? (the code is in a github repo at the bottom of the page)

[R: Backtest Forex Strategies Instantly](https://www.dukascopy.com/fxcomm/fx-article-contest/?R-Backtest-Forex-Strategies-Instantly=&action=read&id=2802&language=en)

He uses a fixed TP at 10% from the start price and a moving SL at 2% from the current price. It may give you a hint of how to do what you are looking for.

EDIT: better than looking at someone else's implementation, take a look at SIT's own approaches to stop loss: https://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/stop-loss/